# How to connect multiple clients to an OpenVPN server using static key auth so they see each other?

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

I have an openvpn server with three clients connected to it using static key authorization.

I need to connect them in a way that the clients can "see" each other. So, for example, I can ping device 1 from device 2 using it's openvpn IP.

The devices have IPs of 10.8.0.{2,3,4}, and I assigned 10.8.0.1 as the server IP for all of them.

When all devices are connected, though, I can't ping 10.8.0.2 from 10.8.0.3, for example.

Here are the server configs:

```
dev tun
port 1196
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.4
secret secret.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
```

(there are three configs on the server, one for each device, each listening on a different port, and each with different secret)

The client configs look like this:

```
remote my-vpn.server 1196
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.1
secret secret.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
```

IP forwaring is enabled on the server.

Is such setup (clients seeing each other) possible with static key authorization?

I know that there's a `client-to-client` option, but it's only available when using TLS, and I'm using static keys instead.

The routing table on the "client" devices look like so:

Looking at the routing table from 10.8.0.3, it seems that the device will direct traffic addressed to 10.8.0.2 through the default gateway instead of the tunnel...

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.8.0.1 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.3 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-318f2bff6bd2 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.16 metric 100
```

Comment: Are they not already talking to each other? Is it blocked in your firewall?

Comment: They can't talk to each other, pinging 10.8.0.2 from 10.8.0.3 doesn't work.

Do you mean firewall on the server or the clients? What's the best way to check it?

Comment: You should check the firewall on all three of the devices. They should already be able to talk to each other. `client-to-client` only means that the OpenVPN server forwards the traffic directly without going through the OS kernel. Without it, the same traffic is handled by the OS, so the OS must be configured to allow it. And of course the firewalls must also allow it.

Comment: I've added the routing table to the original question.

To my understanding the firewall doesn't even have a chance to kick in, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you've found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the `client-to-client` option as it has nothing to do with TLS or static keys.

```
    --client-to-client
        Because the OpenVPN server mode handles multiple clients through a single tun or
        tap interface, it is effectively a router. The --client-to-client flag tells
        OpenVPN to internally route client-to-client traffic rather than pushing all
        client-originating traffic to the TUN/TAP interface.
    
        When this option is used, each client will "see" the other clients which are
        currently connected. Otherwise, each client will only see the server. Don't use
        this option if you want to firewall tunnel traffic using custom, per-client rules.
```

What this option does is to tell the server process to handle the routing within the process and not through the kernel, which, from the clients perspective makes it act more like a LAN switch: if one client wants to reach the other, it can do so without any filtering/routing in place. If you do not supply this option, you should have a very good reason, i.e. why do you want to bother your server with client-to-client traffic?

But if you really want this, e.g. as the man page says, when you want to firewall the traffic, you'll at least have to push the whole VPN subnet to the clients as otherwise, they will see only the client-to-server subnet. Not sure what's required on the server side, i.e. if the server has the whole subnet in its routing table, I'm not sure if it will route at all since, as far as routing logic goes, the clients should have never had to contact the server if they're on the same subnet. So without bothering about firewall rules (which shouldn't block the forwarding), it may also be required to add every client-to-server subnet as a separate route on the server.

**Edit: my working config:**

Server:

```
server 192.168.81.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
```

Client:

```
topology subnet
```

(no `ifconfig` option in either config)